# Disable Contents of onClick function and reuse later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way where I can do something like this?

Disable all `onclick` events for this type of button on default:

```
$('.btn').off('onclick');
```

Cache the elements function:

```
var clickEvent = $('.btn').prop('onclick');
```

Reuse the function:

```
if(form == valid()) {
 //run cached function in var from onclick
}
```

Submit button that has Google Event Tracking code within the `onclick` attribute.

```
  <button class="btn " type="submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label');">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Put the Google event tracking in it's own function, then run the validation in the function, if valid, call tracking code. Dont remove the entire click event then re-attach.

Answer (score 2):

what about not using `onclick`? it's 2015 after all...

```
$('.btn').on('click', send);

function send() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label');
}

$('.btn').off('click', send);
```

alternative way of tackling this scenarios:

```
$('form').on('click', '.bnt:not(.active)', function () {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label');
    $(this).addClass('active'); // disables it
});

$('.btn').removeClass('active'); // re-enables it
```